# rpy2 tests getting "NotImplementedError: Conversion from rpy2 DataFrame to pandas' DataFrame" on ubuntu

Tags: python, r, ubuntu, rpy2

I'll be really grate if someone can help me here.

I'm on ubuntu 13.10 with python 2.7, R 3.0.1 and I've followed the rpy2 installation guide with success up to the tests.

When running the tests via prompt using this command `python -m 'rpy2.tests'` I get the following error:

```
rpy2 version: 2.3.8
built against R version: 3-0.1--62743
............................................................................................ ............................................................................................ .........................................................................................................E...........................................................
======================================================================

ERROR: testPandas2ri
(rpy2.robjects.tests.testPandasConversions.PandasConversionsTestCase)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rpy2/robjects/tests/testPandasConversions.py", line 74, in testPandas2ri
    pandas_df = robjects.conversion.ri2py(rdataf)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rpy2/robjects/pandas2ri.py", line 63, in ri2pandas
    raise NotImplementedError("Conversion from rpy2 DataFrame to pandas' DataFrame")
NotImplementedError: Conversion from rpy2 DataFrame to pandas' DataFrame

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 349 tests in 4.297s
```

I get the same error when installing in python interpreter. Where can I find this conversion pakage?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this code is a bit in flux at the moment. Clearly, there are a number of people (myself included) who use rpy2 and pandas, but rpy2 doesn't yet have a stable built-in converter for this. You could try [this module](https://bitbucket.org/lgautier/rpy2/src/a66387e12e2419141dadb7464ea9205595ef89af/rpy/robjects/pandas2ri.py?at=default) in the current development version of rpy2:

```
from rpy2.robjects.pandas2ri import pands2ri
rpy2.robjects.pandas2ri.activate()
```

It looks like the above code is not yet stable based on comments in the source, so you might be best off writing your own code based off the functions in that module.

You could also try the code from pandas. See here for documentation of the pandas/rpy2 interface (which has in fact been updated since this documentation was written):

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/r_interface.html

and the source code:

https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/rpy/common.py

For example:

```
import pandas.rpy.common as com
r_dataframe = com.convert_to_r_dataframe(df)
```

Feel free to ask a question with specific issues you're having if you can't figure it out.

Comment: rpy2-2.4.0-dev is relatively stable/robust at the time of writing. Copying that code to rpy2-2.3.x in the hope it works is not recommended (and will probably not get you very far): The general conversion system was partly rewritten for 2.4.0 to make the conversion possible.